# Is there a way to show "unrelated" files when working in Android projects in Intellij IDEA Ultimate?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, project

I'm used to working with Spring Boot and general java projects. When working with these I can see all files in the project folder. Things like build files, `dockerfiles` and things like `gitlab-ci.yml` files.
I've recently started working on `Android` projects, and I've noticed in `Intellij Ultimate` (I believe it's the same in Android Studio) I can't see these files in Intellij, I have to go to the project folder in the file system and look at them with some other editor.
Is there any way to make these files visible in my project like they would be if I was developing a Spring Boot application?

I've tried clicking the cog to the right of the project files option and selecting **Tree Appearance -> Show Excluded Files** but it doesn't help, the `yaml` and `Dockerfiles` are still not visible.

Is it possible to show them?

Comment: What scope is selected in project tool window? probably you need to switch from "Android" to "Project".

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: To better understand your setup please attach a screenshot from the [Project View](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html) when `Project` scope is selected and point which files are missing. Also, attach a screenshot from the OS file manager showing the expected result